# Quarkus: clean H2 DB after every test

Tags: java, h2, liquibase, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I set up a standard Quarkus project as described in the quickstart, and I'm now running multiple `@QuarkusTest`, using Liquibase and H2.

I noticed that between tests, the data written in H2 is preserved.

Is my project wrongly configured or does it behave like so for everyone?
Do Quarkus/H2 provide a way to automatically clean all the tables after every test execution?

Comment: I created one auxiliary class in my test package to clean all the tables before every test execution. When is possible, I use the `TestTransaction`, according to [this guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#tests-and-transactions) "If you want any changes made to be rolled back at the end of the test you can use the io.quarkus.test.TestTransaction annotation. This will run the test method in a transaction, but roll it back once the test method is complete to revert any database changes."

Comment: It looks it's working only when I'm testing transactional methods directly. When I'm testing rest endpoints that internally have @Transactional methods, once they are completed and committed, this TestTransaction has no effect apparently..

Comment: That's exactly how the TestTransaction works, it only works when you're testing transactional methods directly. I would also like to have this feature you're suggesting, that is to clean all tables after each test execution. I face the same problem, that's why I created one class on my test package with DELETE executions on all tables. So, in the begging of my test classes, I execute this method that deletes all rows of my tables.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a way to "automatically clean all the tables after every test execution".

One workaround I'm doing is to create one class on the test package and put all the DELETEs needed there. The idea is to run this deletion method on the beginning of the tests that need clean tables.

```java
package org.acme.tests;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@ApplicationScoped
public class CleanTables {

  @Inject
  EntityManager entityManager;

  @Transactional
  public void clean() {
    entityManager.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM YOUR_SCHEMA.YOUR_TABLE_A").executeUpdate();

    entityManager.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM YOUR_SCHEMA.YOUR_TABLE_B").executeUpdate();
  }

}
```